# Change SameSite cookie on the fly in Symfony

Tags: symfony, google-chrome, cookies, samesite

This issue is related to Chrome update where they forced to set `SameSite` attribute (https://www.chromium.org/updates/same-site/incompatible-clients)

Following this link, Chrome 51 to 66 will not accept `SameSite=None`. However, in Symfony settings I have set the following:

```yml
framework:
  ...
  session:
    ...
    cookie_samesite: 'none'
    cookie_secure: true
```

Now, for the Chrome client 51 to 66 I want to change `None` to `Lax`, so this has to be changed on the request level I guess. The part how to detect Chrome version I know, but I am not sure how to apply `Lax` after the device is detected.

I cannot change to `Lax` by default because website can be iframed.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand You correctly, you need to set 2 cookies with same value but with different names. For example:

```php
// main cookie
$cookieFirst = Cookie::create("main_cookie")
                       ->withValue("some_value_here")
                       ->withPath("/")
                       ->withExpires(0)
                       ->withSecure(true)     // important for chrome if SameSite=None
                       ->withHttpOnly(false)  // if you want access via JS
                       ->withRaw(false)
                       ->withSameSite(Cookie::SAMESITE_NONE) // SameSite=None;
// then don't forget to set this cookie to headers
// second cookie
$cookieSecond = Cookie::create("main_cookie.legacy")
                       ->withValue("some_value_here")
                       ->withPath("/")
                       ->withExpires(0)
                       ->withSecure(true)     // important for chrome if SameSite=None
                       ->withHttpOnly(false)  // if you want access via JS
                       ->withRaw(false)
                       ->withSameSite("") // SameSite=Lax;
// then don't forget to set this cookie to headers too
```

I used this approach when implement communication using iframes between domains.

Comment: actually the problem with this that it just sets the cookie on the response, while i need to alter cookie on the request. PHPSESSID must be altered before send to the browser, so i can determine whether that cookie should be Lax or None.